# Network sharing fonts

Tags: macos, font

I've got four iMacs in a design studio and I want to share fonts between them so InDesign documents and the like won't get errors when they're being worked on on any of the machines.

Are there any software solutions or methods for this problem? Don't mind paying, just need it sorted out reliably so that we can have equivalent fonts on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

[Extensis](http://www.extensis.com/universal-type-server/) makes the [Universal Type Server](http://www.extensis.com/universal-type-server/) for this purpose. I have no experience with it.

The [Universal Type Server "Lite" version](https://www.extensis.com/store/universal-type-server-4/), designed for up to 10 users, costs US $1395.

Comment: Cheers! Haven't heard of that one.